# nginx centos 7 server multiple website

Tags: nginx, centos

my server ip is 103.107.122.13 and port:5680.
i want two application suppose 103.107.122.13:5680/test1 then it enter var/www/html/test1 website and  103.107.122.13:5680/test2 it enter var/www/html/test2 website using virtual host. please tell me how can i manage this need also any change in nginx.conf file .

if anyone know please help me to solve this problem .
I already write two file inside site-available folder test1.conf file

```
server {
        listen   80;
        location /test1{
          root /var/www/html/test1;
          index  index.php;
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

and  test2.conf file

```
server {
        listen   80;
        location /test2{
          root /var/www/html/test2;
          index  index.php;
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why different files? You should put this to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
http {
    server {
        listen   80;

        location /test1{
          root /var/www/html/test1;
          index  index.php;
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /test2{
          root /var/www/html/test2;
          index  index.php;
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: different file create any problem ?